# decrement for loop does not iterate

Tags: c#

```
     static void Main()
        {

            double[] MPCV = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }; //MPCV = velocity for MPC 
            double[] MPCW = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }; // MPCW = omega for MPC


            double G1 = 0.04, G2 = 0.04, T = 20E-06;


            int k, n = 5, count;

            double[] X = new double[6];
            double[] Y = new double[6];
            double[] A = new double[6];


            int tx = 700;
            double ta = (Math.PI / 180) * 60;
            int ty = 300;

            double[,] qd = new double[3, 1] { { tx }, { ty }, { ta } };
            double[,] Lamda5 = new double[1, 3]; //lamda(5) transpose
            double[,] qk = new double[6, 3]; //q(k) matrix
            double[,] r = new double[3, 1]; //q(5)-qd
            double[,] Z = new double[3, 3]; //df/dq


            X[0] = 500;
            Y[0] = 600;
            A[0] = (Math.PI / 180) * 90; //converting from degree to radian




            for (count = 0; count < 30; count++) //main loop for MPC controller
            {

                for (k = 0; k < n; k++) // loop to find q(k) = [x[k] y[k] A[k]]
                {
                    X[k + 1] = X[k] + (T * MPCV[k]) * Math.Cos(A[k]); // state space model for X,Y,Angle
                    Y[k + 1] = Y[k] + (T * MPCV[k]) * Math.Sin(A[k]);
                    A[k + 1] = A[k] + (T * MPCW[k]);

                    Console.WriteLine("\nX({0}) = {1} \nY({0}) = {2} \nX({0}) = {3} ", k + 1, X[k + 1], Y[k + 1], A[k + 1]);

                    for (int j = 0; j <= n; j++) //update q(k) as a matrix
                    {
                        qk[j, 0] = X[j];
                        qk[j, 1] = Y[j];
                        qk[j, 2] = A[j];

                        Console.WriteLine("\nthe matrix is q({0}) =[X={1} Y={2}  A={3}]", j, qk[j, 0], qk[j, 1], qk[j, 2]);
                    }
                }
                //end first for loop for q(k)

                double X5 = qk[n, 0];
                double Y5 = qk[n, 1];

                r[0, 0] = X5 - tx;
                r[1, 0] = Y5 - ty;
                r[2, 0] = 0;
                Console.WriteLine("\nthe matrix is q(N) =[X={1} Y={1}  A={2}]", r[0, 0], r[1, 0], r[2, 0]);

                Lamda5[0, 0] = G1 * r[0, 0];
                Lamda5[0, 1] = G1 * r[1, 0];
                Lamda5[0, 2] = G1 * r[2, 0];

                Console.WriteLine("\nthe matrix is LamdaN =[X={1} Y={1}  A={2}]", Lamda5[0, 0], Lamda5[0, 1], Lamda5[0, 2]);

                for (k = n; k <= 1; k--) // loop for lamda
                {

                    Z[0, 0] = 1;
                    Z[0, 1] = 0;
                    Z[0, 2] = -T * MPCV[k] * (Math.Sin(A[k]));

                    Z[1, 0] = 1;
                    Z[1, 1] = 0;
                    Z[1, 2] = -T * MPCV[k] * (Math.Cos(A[k]));

                    Z[2, 0] = 0;
                    Z[2, 1] = 0;
                    Z[2, 2] = 1;


                    Console.WriteLine("\nthe matrix is Z =[X={1} Y={1}  A={2}]", Z[0,0], Z[0,1], Z[0,2]);
                    Console.WriteLine("\nthe matrix is Z =[X={1} Y={1}  A={2}]", Z[1,0], Z[1,1], Z[1,0]);
                    Console.WriteLine("\nthe matrix is Z =[X={1} Y={1}  A={2}]", Z[2,0], Z[2,1], Z[2,0]);
                }
}
```

Hi, I have tried to do the iteration for the loop for `lamda` as described by my comment line.  However, it does not iterate and no output for matrix `Z` is shown.  Have I made some mistake somewhere? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

```
for (k = n; k <= 1; k--)
```

is *very* unusual in that the continuation condition is checking if `k` is *less* than or equal to one.

If `n` is greater than one (and it is since you set it to `5`), that loop body will never be executed.

You should be using `>=` rather than `<=`.

Comment: Thank you. i mix up with k++ i suppose.

Answer (score 1):

> Have i make some mistake somewhere?

Yes - your condition requires that `k` be less than or equal to 1, but you *start* at 5, so the block never executes.

change your loop condition to

```
for (k = n; k >= 1; k--)
```

Comment: Thank you. i mix up with k++ i suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Your For loop Condition is wrong.

You just made a mistake in greater and less then sign.

You want to loop till K is greater or equal to 1.

But you you checked to loop till K is Less then 1.

So you just need to correct condition.

```
for (k = n; k >= 1; k--) // loop for lambda                
{
}
```

Comment: Thank you. i mix up with k++ i suppose.